# How to use one function for both rows and columns in 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have a sort function for 1D array

```
void sort(int a[], int n){
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
           if (a[i] > a[j]){
               temp = a[j];
               a[j] = a[i];
               a[i] = temp;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I know how to make it sort all rows of 2D array:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       sort(b[i], m); // b is 2d array n - rows m - columns
```

But I'm wondering what do I have to change, to be able to use the **same** function to sort columns instead?

Comment: This is not possible unfortunately. You will have to copy the column contents to a temporary array, then sort that array. (Or , similarly, make a temporary array of refs to the original array and sort the refs)

Comment: Change the function to take the entire 2D array. Pass your function the column number also. Access your elements by both row number (your iteration values) and passed column number.

Comment: This same function cant sort the columns of 2D array

Comment: Yes I know I'll probably need to change the function itself so I can use it in both cases.

Comment: @M.M: Why is it not possible? It is commonly done by passing the address of the first element of the two-dimensional array and a stride that is a number of physical elements between subject elements. That does abuse C’s pointer arithmetic, but that can be worked around by doing the address calculations in `char` units.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP wanted to use the posted code to sort the column

Comment: @M.M: I see no impediment to sorting a column given sufficient information to identify the locations of the elements of the column.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you post a MCVE showing that , with the `sort` function in the question unchanged?

Comment: @M.M: The question does not ask how to use the same source as shown in the question to sort columns. It asks how to use the same source to sort columns as to sort rows. In other words, to change the function in the question so it can be used to sort rows and can be used to sort columns.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the accepted answer doesn't fit that interpretation , maybe you could write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the sort function to traverse through columns by passing an extra argument:

```
void sort(int a[n][m], int n, int col_index){
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
           if (a[i][col_index] > a[j][col_index]){
               temp = a[j][col_index];
               a[j][col_index] = a[i][col_index];
               a[i][col_index] = temp;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

And then implement as follows

```
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    sort(b,n,i);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `int a[][],` is an error. Only the innermost brackets may be left empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Special_transpose_matrices) the incoming 2D array to exchange rows and columns and do the normal sorting.

maybe add a flag to determine if you need to do `transpose` or not